# Getting repeated value in a group_concat only if ids are different

Tags: mysql, select, group-concatenation

I have two tables, first the table Product:

```
id|category_id
--+-----------
1 | 12345
2 | 12345
3 | 12465
```

And then a table activity:

```
id|prod_id|activity_type   |description
--+-------+----------------+-----------
1 | 1     | Initialization | blah
2 | 1     | Finalization   | foo
3 | 2     | Initialization | blah again
4 | 2     | Duplication    | bar
5 | 2     | Finalization   | foobar
6 | 3     | Initialization | blob
7 | 3     | Migration      | A to B
8 | 3     | Migration      | B to C
9 | 3     | Finalization   | fuh
```

Now I want to retrieve for each type of activity the number of product having at least one of this kind of activity, and also the list of product category. The categories will be repeated in the list for each product of this category. For now I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT a.activity_type as Activity, COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) as Products,
CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(p.category SEPARATOR ',  ') USING utf8) AS Categories
FROM mydb.product p, mydb.activity a
WHERE p.id = a.prod_id
AND a.activity_type <> '' // To not count activities which haven't been correctly initialized
GROUP BY Categories
ORDER BY Products
```

Now what I await for result is:

```
Activity       | Products | Categories
---------------+----------+--------------------
Initialization | 3        | 12345, 12345, 12465
Finalization   | 3        | 12345, 12345, 12465
Duplication    | 1        | 12345
Migration      | 1        | 12465
```

But with this query I get the value `'12465, 12465'` for Migration. I could I get that a category appears on the list, only for each different product ids, but not for each activity of one type?

Comment: do you mean that you want to get the number of products with a specific activity_type. For example, Migration has 1 distinct prod_id (3).  You now want to only get one category_id (12465) and not 2 (12465, 12465) like you now get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First group by both `activity_type` and `prod_id` and then another group by `activity_type`:

```
SELECT 
    a.activity_type AS Activity, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS Products,
    CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(p.category_id SEPARATOR ',  ') USING utf8) 
      AS Categories
FROM 
    product AS p
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT activity_type
           , prod_id
      FROM activity 
      WHERE activity_type <> '' 
      GROUP BY activity_type
             , prod_id
    ) AS a
    ON p.id = a.prod_id
GROUP BY 
    activity_type
ORDER BY 
    Products DESC;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86dac/34)** (thank you @Mr.Radical)

You could also safely replace `COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)` with `COUNT(*)` in the above, as for every activity type, there are only distinct product IDs (this is taken care in the internal group by).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't knew one could use a Select query as some kind of pseudo-table. Should I consider that the result of such a query is in fact a table?

Comment: It depends on what you define as "table". These are usually called "derived tables". Meaning that they are not base tables, they are not permanently stored. There is also another type of table, called views. They are similar to the derived tables but they have a name and they can be used in many other queries (without the need to define them every time as the derived table here). Views are also not base tables and are usually not stored permanently (except some DBMS that allow them to be "persisted"). So, to answer your question, yes, such a query is a table but not a "base" table.

Comment: And that many people when they use the term "table" they really or often mean "base table".

Answer (score 0):

Oke, I got it solved. Try this:

```
SELECT a.activity_type, COUNT(DISTINCT( p.id)) AS products, 
CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (p.category_id) SEPARATOR ',  ') USING utf8) AS Categories 
FROM activity as a 
LEFT JOIN Product AS p ON p.id = a.prod_id
WHERE a.activity_type <> ''
GROUP BY a.activity_type
ORDER BY products DESC;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Product
    (`id` int, `category_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO Product
    (`id`, `category_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 12345),
    (2, 12345),
    (3, 12465)
;

CREATE TABLE Activity
    (`id` int, `prod_id` int, `activity_type` varchar(14), `description` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Activity
    (`id`, `prod_id`, `activity_type`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Initialization', 'blah'),
    (2, 1, 'Finalization', 'foo'),
    (3, 2, 'Initialization', 'blah again'),
    (4, 2, 'Duplication', 'bar'),
    (5, 2, 'Finalization', 'foobar'),
    (6, 3, 'Initialization', 'blob'),
    (7, 3, 'Migration', 'A to B'),
    (8, 3, 'Migration', 'B to C'),
    (9, 3, 'Finalization', 'fuh')
;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86dac/36

Comment: My first thought was this, too. But it doesn't show 3 items in the `Categories` columns (as wanted) in the "Initialization" and "Finalization" groups.

Comment: @ypercube you are correct my query doesn't show the requested 3 items. Yours answer does.